# How could I use the blueprint to split all routes into sub-modules

Tags: python, flask

Here's my repo https://github.com/poc7667/flask_blueprint

I want to separate all routes into sub-modules,

and i will run `python web.py` in the root folder

I hope I can access the route `/hihi` under `sub_1` module by `http://localhost:8888/hihi`

However I got `Not found error`

## web.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
from sub_1 import sub_1_mod
app.register_blueprint(sub_1_mod, url_prefix="/")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=8888)
```

## sub_1/web.py

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from sub_1 import sub_1_mod
from flask import Flask, Response, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/hihi", methods=['GET'])
def hihi():
    return make_response(["hihi"], VERSION)
```

## sub_1/**init**.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
sub_1_mod = Blueprint('sub_1', __name__)
import sub_1.web
```

## Exception

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **sub_1/web.py**, do not create another `Flask` application. Instead, add the route to the existing [blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/#my-first-blueprint)

```
from sub_1 import sub_1_mod
@sub_1_mode.route("/hihi", methods=['GET'])
def hihi():
    return make_response(["hihi"], VERSION)
```